# Python - How to match list elements by character to character

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

I have two list

```
List1 = ['hello','welcome','india','nation']
List2 = ['ind', 'nat','hellooo','welcomeeee']
```

i want to compare elements and print as below -

Output :

```
['india','nation','hello','welcome']
```

please suggest some optimized way.

I am having list with unspecified size in each, but it has one list elements matches another list elements, as random, i don't know the size of highest / longest possible match in any of the list.

Comment: How exactly do you want to compare the elements?

Comment: I suppose the output should be with "nat" and not "nation", also with "ind" and not "india"

Comment: "An optimzed way?" Do you have some code that inplements this in a not optimized way that you can share? Any limit on complexity? There's a pretty straightforward quadratic time solution here.

Comment: @pault I have tried splitting list by indexes but its not accurate. As I don't know the max limit of any of the list element (size)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to determine the closest match, so here is one implementation of Levenshtein:

```
def levenshteinDistance(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) > len(s2):
        s1, s2 = s2, s1

    distances = range(len(s1) + 1)
    for i2, c2 in enumerate(s2):
        distances_ = [i2+1]
        for i1, c1 in enumerate(s1):
            if c1 == c2:
                distances_.append(distances[i1])
            else:
                distances_.append(1 + min((distances[i1], distances[i1 + 1], distances_[-1])))
        distances = distances_
    return distances[-1]


List1 = ['hello', 'welcome', 'india', 'nation']
List2 = ['ind', 'nat', 'helloooo', 'welcomeeeeee']

[min(zip(List1, [levenshteinDistance(j, i) for j in List1]), key=lambda x: x[1])[0] for i in List2]
#['india', 'nation', 'hello', 'welcome']
```

Comment: Probably overkill to implement your own Levenshtein function, but at least this gets the correct output. **Edit**: I am not the downvoter

Comment: @pault Thanks for not downvoting :) Well, I like Levenshtein and use every chance to promote it :)

Comment: I still have some confusion in this. I am not getting output as require.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [@AndreiDurnea's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53082372/9209546), you can also use a generator:

```
def comparer(L1, L2):
    for i in L2:
        for j in L1:
            if (i in j) or (j in i):
                yield j

List1 = ['hello','welcome','india','nation']
List2 = ['ind', 'nat','helloooo','welcomeeeeee']

res = list(comparer(List1, List2))

['india', 'nation', 'hello', 'welcome']
```

As per @pault's comment, [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) with a list comprehension may be more efficient than a generator:

```
from itertools import product

res = [j for i, j in product(List2, List1) if (i in j) or (j in i)]
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension,

```
In [14]: [j for i in List2 for j in List1 if i in j or j in i]
Out[14]: ['india', 'nation', 'hello', 'welcome']
```

Comment: I like this [i for i in List1 for j in List2 if i in j or j in i]. 
Can you please point me where I can explore more of this sintax sugar?

Comment: Can you please explain in more details.?

Comment: @pault Updated my answer. Btw that's for the mention

Answer (score -1):

```
List1 = ['hello','welcome','india','nation']
List2 = ['ind', 'nat','helloooo','welcomeeeeee']

Rezult = []

for firstItem in List1:
    for secondItem in List2: 
        if firstItem in secondItem or secondItem in firstItem:
            Rezult.append(firstItem)
            continue

print(Rezult)
```

the output for this is:

```
['hello', 'welcome', 'india', 'nation']
```

I would suggest to rename the variables:

```
list_1 = ['hello','welcome','india','nation']
list_2 = ['ind', 'nat','helloooo','welcomeeeeee']

rezult = []

for firstItem in list_1:
    for secondItem in list_2: 
        if firstItem in secondItem or secondItem in firstItem:
            rezult.append(firstItem)            

print(rezult)
```

Comment: @pault Can you please explain in more details.?

Comment: Look at the order of the output.

Comment: Oh that means It's printing only first list, Any other alternate solution for this.?

Comment: @naitik_chandakna use jpp's answer